# About a popup on the map in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a question about OpenLayers.
I want to display a popup on a map as shown in the figure.
Then I scroll to the right side and after one round of the globe, the popup is no longer displayed.
The icon is still displayed.
Is this a specification?
Or am I making it the wrong way?

openlayers -> popup

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html

[image]

Comment: There is only one overlay and overlays do not wrap automatically -  you could move it with the view by listening for `change:center` events, for example  https://codesandbox.io/s/popup-forked-mgckyc?file=/main.js

Comment: Hi, thank you for your code. I could solve my problem.

Comment: In your sample code, the value of center is within a certain range. But in my case, as I continue to scroll through the map, the value continues to increase. I don't know why.